# Protection of the pins of an electronic board against overvoltage due to a bad connection

Tags: output, input, pins, over-voltage-protection

I designed an electronic board with two inputs connected to an ADC (MCP3202), one output connected to the output of an AOP (INA105) and a 24V battery supply.

My question is: is there a way to protect the ADC inputs and the AOP output from a power surge due to bad wiring? If the 24V battery power is connected to the ADC input or the AOP output by mistake, can these components be protected?

For the ADC, I made a protection using clamps but this protection works only if the card is powered. A position sensor sends a current between 4 and 20 mA. A parallel resistor of 250 ohms allows to obtain a voltage between 1 and 5V at the input of the ADC.

[image]

The AOP INA105 allows me to obtain a current between -10/+10mA depending on the input voltage, this one being given by a DAC (DAC7612).

[image]

I hope to have been clear, I thank you in advance for your time.
Have a nice day.